# OpenVPN client behind corporate firewall

Tags: vpn, firewall, openvpn, udp

I cannot connect from the corporate network at work to my OpenVPN server. However, with client and server settings untouched, connecting from other networks works.

I can only assume that this is due to a filter on the corporate firewall. Now, I wonder what I could do to still get through.

The server uses UDP 1194. Changing to a different UDP port did not help.

The error message I receive is 'No response from server'.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from changing the port as mentioned already (expecially 443 which being HTTPS is usually not filtered) there are two more things I may suggest:

1) use TCP instead of UDP (just use "proto tcp-server" and "proto tcp-client" in configs)

2) if your corporate network has a HTTP proxy (quite often happens there is one and other ports are cut) then you could try to pass through it (see [http-proxy](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#http) config options in openvpn)

Comment: I really appreciate the quick, quality replys!

There is no HTTP proxy.

I tried TCP on multiple different ports. It is blocked as well.
While HTTPS goes through, tcp 443 port forwarded to my tcp openvpn server is being blocked.

I get the feeling they use a DPI firewall here. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using port 443 instead. This is the trick for-pay OpenVPN services will teach you to try and avoid firewalls, ISP limitations, and so on. The reason is that port 443 is, possibly, the last one to be blocked by a firewall.

Edit:

Other possibilities, besides those mentioned by fede-evol, are also:

1. Try port 80, if you do not have a Web server at home;
   1.Try some other port that is not likely to be blocked, like 8080;
2. Bounce the communication off a friend's pc, from port 443 to port 1194 and viceversa;
3. get a cheap VPS, to bounce the communication back home.
4. use a *reverse tunnel*, initiated from your work pc to your home pc. In this case, you may use just any port you like, including port 80 or 41367, or ...

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Too bad my cheap as DSL modem doesn't allow forwarding 443 as it insists to run the admin GUI on that port.

Comment: @Marcel I have added a few possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, that's some great stuff!

to 1.: Tried, not working. See comments above.
t0 2. and 3.: Too complex for me who's only working as a consultant and might be on a different engagement in some months or just weeks
to 4.: I will have to look into this. Any good how-tos?

Comment: For which OS? I might as well give you the right ref